# Wifi connection is really slow after a while, but disconnecting and connecting again speeds it up

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-speed

After I connect to my home wifi network, I get very high speeds, but after a couple of seconds I get a slow internet again. It is happening to both my Android phone and my Linux PC, but my phone gets the biggest speed hit and is unable to load a video properly sometimes. It is getting really annoying, because some websites need to get refreshed to start loading a video again and that loses all progress. Does anyone know the cause?

Edit: The router model is TL-WR841N (with `0.9.1 4.16 v0001.0 Build 180319 Rel.57291n` version firmware) and I am using the 2.4 GHz band.

Comment: Get a better router.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I thinj this is on topic here.  You should add more details like the make and model of the router and what band(s) you are using.

Comment: I wonder if you have a device that is usimg a lot of bandwidth without you being aware of it and when you add a new device you briefly disrupt the "load balancing" of the router providing a burst of high speed to the new device.  It could also be an interference issue with other devices or just band router firmware.

Comment: Assuming bluetooth is on, what happens if you disable bluetooth?

Comment: @Yorik If I disable it, the network connection gets a little better, but still takes a hit, when I don't reconnect after a while.